# nested dag default arguments in airflow

Tags: arguments, airflow, directed-acyclic-graphs

I currently use following BigQuery Operator in airflow:

```
  s10_test = bigquery.BigQueryInsertJobOperator(
            task_id="10_test",
            configuration={
                    "query": {
                                "query": "SELECT CURRENT_DATE",
                                "useLegacySql": False,
                    }
            },
               )
```

I would like to avoid to specify useLegacySql in every task and just pass this parameter as a default argument. Is it any special syntax required for nested arguments?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try passing a query without this parameter?

If it throws out an error without this parameter, then you may not have much of a choice. If it doesn't, then you can try and see which SQL (standard/legacy) it runs by default?

If you don't want to pass this parameter, you can always wrap this function inside a small utility function that you can use anywhere. Like:

```py
from airflow.providers.google.cloud.operators import bigquery
from airflow.providers.google.cloud.transfers import bigquery_to_gcs

def BigQueryInsertJobOperator(params={}):
   task_id = params.get("task_id")
   query = params.get("query")
   response = None
   if (query and task_id):
      response = bigquery.BigQueryInsertJobOperator(
         task_id=task_id,
         configuration={"query": {"query": query, "useLegacySql": False}},
      )
   return response
```

and call it everywhere in your scripts like:

```py
from utilities import BigQueryInsertJobOperator

params = {"query": "SELECT CURRENT_DATE", "task_id": "test_1"}
response = BigQueryInsertJobOperator(params=params)
```